# Cyanogen: add homescreen shortcut to Notifications

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications, home-screen-shortcuts, adw.launcher

I'm using Cyanogen 7 on an HTC Wildfire.

I find swiping the top of the screen to get into Notifications a bit hit and miss, and too tiring : )

Is there some way to get a notifications shortcut onto the homescreen (or the menu for the homescreen).

For example, the Sense ROM had a shortcut to notifications in the homescreen menu, and that was pretty handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the default version of ADW Launcher that comes with CyanogenMod 7 then you can add a shortcut to your homescreen fairly easily. Long press on an empty space on one of your home screens and then select `Launcher Actions->Open/close notifications` to add the shortcut.

On older versions of ADW you can also do this, but you have to use a "custom shortcut" instead. Specifically, you long press on an empty space and then select `Custom shortcut`. Then on the dialog that appears you press the `Pick your activity` button and select `Launcher Actions->Open/close notifications`.

I'm not aware of any way to make it appear in the homescreen menu, unfortunately. It's one of the only features I miss from Sense.